Find a map $f: T^2 \rightarrow T^2$ with $\deg (f) = 0$, but so that $f$ is not null-homotopic.
This question is from a publicly available old qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I consulted Hatcher's book for this problem, but I have seen no proof for this problem anywhere; all work is my own.


Find a map $f: T^2 \rightarrow T^2$ with $\deg  (f) = 0$, but so that $f$ is not null-homotopic

Answer:
I reviewed Hatcher's book by looking for null-homotopic in his index, and I only saw one brief mention in his introduction. I then consulted some online resources, and the gist I got was that the image is homotopic to a constant function, which is equivalent to stating that it is contractible to a point within the domain.
Now, we can also write our map as $f: (S^1 \times S^1) \rightarrow (S^1 \times S^1)$.
Hatcher tells us on page 135 that the degree of $f$ is zero if $f$ is not surjective. From here, define our map by $f(x, y) = (x, \alpha)$ for some constant $\alpha$. That is, $f$ has as its image some circle in the torus $T^2$. This map is clearly non-surjective, so $\deg(f) = 0$.
However, the image (this circle) can't be contracted to a point within the range (the torus). Thus the map is not null-homotopic either. Clearly then, our map $f$ satisfies the criteria.

(a) Did I properly understand and apply the idea of null-homotopy? Hatcher's criteria for a degree-zero map seemed cut and dry, but there's a dearth of information in his book regarding null-homotopy.
As a usual bonus, if anyone has any approach that they find cleaner, more efficient, (or correct if mine isn't), then feel free to let me know. Thanks in advance.

Your example is correct but the justification is not: a map can be null-homotopic while it's image is not.

@MoisheKohan Is there a way to consistently gauge whether a map is null homotopic by looking at the domain and range? Dearth of examples I could find online, so I’d be grateful for more detail on why my example still works.

No. You have to learn a bit more algebraic topology to solve such problems (like being able to compute induced maps of fundamental groups).

@MoisheKohan Book recommendation then? I couldn't find anything beyond one sentence in Hatcher, and in some of the other books I looked at I couldn't find anything.

Null-homotopic maps induce zero maps on homology and homotopy groups.

@JohnPalmieri Then for $H_1 (T^2) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$, the induced map $f^*$ gives for $H_1$ the mapping $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \mapsto \mathbb Z$, which is not a zero map, and thus demonstrates that our map is not null-homotopic?

If you can verify that $f_*$ is nonzero, then yes, the map must be null-homotopic.
